# Parse Local DataStore not showing pinned data

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, local-datastore

I have tried to make sure that all the recommended steps are followed in implementing Parse local data store but either pinning seems to be not working or querying the pinned objects is not working. I have tried multiple options. Below is my code for the view controller and also I have enabled the datastore etc in the app delegate file as well (using the base parse starter project). Please advise me where is the problem.

Output in my console - i am able to fetch data from the parse server but am either not able to pin it properly or retrieve it properly or something else..

```
 Success 8888 
Optional([])
Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.
success 7777
Optional([<Restaurant: 0x7f98ca521f60, objectId: 0rRZNCndje, localId: (null)> {
    Name = time;
}])
```

Thanks for the help!

```
import Foundation
import Parse
import ParseUI
import UIKit
import Foundation

class RestaurantAdmin: ViewController {
    func getDataFromLocalDataStore() {
        var userName = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
        var messages2: [AnyObject]!
        var query2: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Restaurant")
        query2.fromLocalDatastore()
        query2.whereKey("Owner", equalTo: userName!)
        query2.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                messages2 = objects
                println(" Success 8888 ")
                println(objects)
            }
            else {
                println("Fail 8888")
            }
        }
    }

    func refreshRestaurantDataFromServer() {
        var userName = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Restaurant")
        query.whereKey("Owner", equalTo: userName!)
        query.selectKeys(["Name"])
        var messages: [AnyObject]!
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                PFObject.pinAllInBackground(objects, block: nil)
                println("success 7777")
                println(objects)
            }
            else {
                println("error 7777")
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if (PFUser.currentUser()?.username != nil) {
            refreshRestaurantDataFromServer()
        }
        getDataFromLocalDataStore()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `query.selectKeys(["Name"])` the whole object is not downloaded. Now you are saving this partial object and then querying using `query2.whereKey("Owner", equalTo: userName!)`. The saved object does not contain the `"Owner"` key.

Comment: Hi Santhosh, I even commented query2.whereKey("Owner", equalTo: userName!) and I am now expecting all the objects of class Restaurant will be queried. I still don't get any data in my query. Do I need to do anything different?

Comment: I tried downloading the entire object and it worked. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Please mark it as an answer if u found my answer useful. Thanks.

Comment: One question, can we use parse to store data ONLY locally like SQLite and Core-Data?